# Getting graphql response value from onResponse method using ApolloClient

Tags: java, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-java

I'm trying to get result of GraphQL query through ApolloClient, I've tried assigning the result to global variable and I get the value in the onResponse method, however outside that i get the value my variable has been declared as at first. The onResponse method is generated automatically by apollo and the query puts up and error if deleted.
Is there a way to get the response out somehow ?

```
public class Main {

    public static String result = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApolloClient apolloClient = ApolloClient.builder().serverUrl("https://apollo-fullstack-tutorial.herokuapp.com/graphql").build();

        apolloClient.query(new LaunchDetailsQuery("83"))
                .enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<LaunchDetailsQuery.Data>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NotNull Response<LaunchDetailsQuery.Data> response) {
                        result=response.getData().launch.mission.name;
                        System.out.println(result);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NotNull ApolloException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                });

        System.out.println(result);
    }


}
```

Tried assigning the value to global variable, appending the value into list through setters from another class. Always returns as the objects first init value.